# Excel VBA: Changes to all sheets on same cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a weird error:

I have a workbook with 20 sheets in it.  I select one of the sheets and edit one individual cell
in that sheet.  When I make the change, however, it is changed to that value in the corresponding cell in ALL of the sheets.

So, for example, if the corresponding cells are "apple", "orange", "banana" (Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3).  When I change "orange" to "grape", the cells are now: "grape", "grape", "grape".

It does not always occur, and sometimes occurs after I run a specific macro, but that macro should not make real-time changes, only when I run the program.

Thank You for the help.

Comment: And you are sure the worksheets aren't Grouped..?

Comment: ... ie. you have more than one sheet selected. This can happen if you hold down control or shift while clicking on a tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may be some event-procedure code running for the workbook or worksheet objects.

Right click a sheet-tab and choose `View Code`. There may be some code shown on the `Change` or `SelectionChange` event.

From the Project Explorer on the left, double-click into each worksheet object and the ThisWorkbook object to discover if they contain any code.

Comment: I checked, none of the worksheets have code (I am doing some developing on an excel workbook that was passed down to me), only the macro I added. And the worksheets are definitely not grouped. I'm starting to think its the macro I wrote... I posted a new question, here is the link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17928961/excel-vba-copy-paste-macro-is-inducing-grouped-worksheet-functionality